# Rails: What's the difference between lambda, scope and class method? What's best practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

The `code` snippet has three methods: `lambda`, `scope` and `class method`.

All of them returns the same results.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any best practice in `Ruby/Rails` when it is preferred to use one over the other ?
2. In what cases would you use `lambda`, `scope` or `class` method ( best practices ).

   ```
   class Cars < ActiveRecord::Base     
     attr_accessible :manufacturer, :price, :used

     #one
     scope :used_and_cheap_lambda, lambda { where('used = ?', true ).where('price >= ?',30000) }

     #two
     scope :used_and_cheap_scope, where('used = ?', true ).where('price >= ?',30000)

     #three
     def self.used_and_cheap_class
       where('used = ?', true ).where('price >= ?',30000)
     end
   end





   Cars.used_and_cheap_lambda.count
   => #24

   Cars.used_and_cheap_class.count
   => #24

   Cars.used_and_cheap_scope.count
   => #24
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's best to avoid using option 2. That code gets run immediately when your Rails app loads which is bad since it will always return the same value for any Time argument you use in it. That's because it isn't reevaluated every time it's called.

Option 1, as pointed out by musicnerd47, are lazy loaded and it is advisable that you pass lambdas to scopes in Rails 4 rather than doing option 2 since they are reevaluated every time called so they will return updated values.

So the only options would be 1 and 3. This is usually a matter of style that your team adheres to. In our company, we use option 1 when the code we pass to it is going to be an ActiveRecord query and we want it to output a query that can be chained. This is to ensure that an ActiveRecord::Relation object is returned every time we do our queries for multiple records. That would mean that they are always going to be chainable with other ActiveRecord::Relation methods and our other defined scopes.

We use option 3 if it's for behavior that doesn't need to be chained with other scopes.

Here's a good read on the matter of scopes and class_methods where he goes into detail and provides examples on the difference between scopes and class methods.
http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/

Comment: Um, ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes. These methods will still be accessible on the association objects"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) so class methods really are scopes like any others and they chain like any other scope. And earlier they even say ["This is exactly the same as defining a class method, and which you use is a matter of personal preference"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) about `scope`.

Comment: That might be the case for others or at least the one who wrote the guide. However, it is not a strict rule but a guideline. There's nothing stopping you from using a scope that accepts arguments. And no, class methods aren't always chainable since they don't always return an ActiveRecord::Relation object.

Comment: Yes, you're free to make a big mess with lambdas that take arguments but the recommended best practice is to use a class method, `scope` is just a fancy way of adding a class method after all. So every scope is, in fact, a class method and all the class methods are available on the return relation objects; not every class method is a scope though.   "We use option 3 if it's for behavior that doesn't need to be chained with other scopes." doesn't make sense because use `def self.x` or `scope :x` has no effect whatsoever on chaining.

Comment: Read this blog post http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/ which will clarify what I mean by scope always making sure that you chain it with other scopes and methods from ActiveRecord::Relation.

Answer (score 4):

Starting in Rails 4 you have to use a lambda - in general it is a better practice because it is lazily loaded and prevents a lot of traps, especially when dealing with dates and times.

I think for simple scopes that deal with a single where call or something, using `scope` is okay. When it is more complex, then moving to a class method is better (for example, when you need to be calling other methods or setting local variables before you return the scope).

Comment: Logan Serman - thanks for answer.Can you please specify what kind of traps to you mean? ( you mentioned dates and times )

Comment: If you have a scope that involves for example `Time.now` (or similar), that will be evaluated when the class is loaded (when you boot up your Rails app). So `Time.now` will not be accurate, it will be the time when the class was loaded. Using a lambda will lazy load the scope, so `Time.now` will be called when the scope is called and will be what you expect.

Comment: You don't have to use a lambda, option 2 is no longer available in Rails4's ActiveRecord but using `scope` is ["is exactly the same as defining a class method, and which you use is a matter of personal preference"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) and ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) so sometimes a class method is officially preferred.

Comment: What do you mean don't have to use a lambda? All of the examples on the page you linked use a lambda. IIRC, there is a deprecation warning when not using a lambda (unless this was removed in a patch > 4.0.0?)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the lambda. The function you're describing is sufficiently simple. Using the lambda initializes lazily as well. I direct you [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide) to the rails style guide.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no golden rule.  Scopes are designed for this exact application.  When the application of logic comfortably fits into a scope, I think that's the best bet.  When things start to get too complex, it's usually best to move the logic into a class method.